# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only SSLv3 was enabled - com.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3 set to TRUE

Tags: java, spring, https, ssl-certificate, websphere-8

Trying to consume soap webservice i.e. of  'https://' type. setting below system properties in my AppConfig.java.

```
@PostConstruct

public void init(){

Security.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider",
            "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl");
    Security.setProperty("ssl.ServerSocketFactory.provider",
            "com.ibm.jsse2.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl");
    System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs",
            "com.ibm.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");

    try {
        if(trustStore!= null){
            File certFile = new File(trustStore);
            if(certFile.exists()){
                System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",trustStorePassword);

                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", trustStore);
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",trustStorePassword);
                String trustStoreType = "JKS";
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType",trustStoreType);
                System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");
                printSysProps();
            }}catch(Exception e){...}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming back because later releases of Java have the SSLv3 protocol disabled by default. So when you try to set and use the SSLv3 protocol in your code it complains because it is disabled.

SSLv3 is no longer considered secure, so really it should not be used. If the server you are trying to communicate with supports newer more secure TLS protocols, I would suggest trying those.

I would not enable SSLv3 on your Java install, as the other comment suggested you could do, unless you absolutely need to.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set system property as shown below:

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3", "false");
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion , i tried setting that and getting exception
  org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: